# React - Send cookie to Express

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, token, session-cookies

I am getting a token to access an API endpoint and I want to send this token to my server-side app (expressJS) to retreive the data.

I have the following for my react app:

```
export default class Account extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          token: null,
          response: {

          }
        };
        this.getCurrentlyPlaying = this.getCurrentlyPlaying.bind(this);
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        // Set token
        let _token = hash.access_token;
        if (_token) {
          this.setState({
            token: _token
          });
          const cookies = new Cookies();
          cookies.set('token', _token, { path: '/' });
          console.log(cookies.get('token'));
          this.getCurrentlyPlaying(_token);
        }
      }

      getCurrentlyPlaying() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/account`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState ({
              response: data
          })
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
    render() {
       if (this.state.response[0].is_playing  === true) {
        return (
          <p> Something is playing</p>
         );
       }
       else {
         return (
          <p> Nothing is playing</p>
         );
       }
    }
}
```

In my express app, I have the cookie being gotten but I'm not sure if it actually is getting the cookie created by the react app:

```
  router.get('/account', (req, res) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${req.session.token}`
      }
    };
    fetch(`${CONFIG.spotifyUrl}/me/player/currently-playing `, config)
    .then(html => html.json())
    .then(json => {
      res.json(json);
    });
  });
module.exports = router;
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: use document.cookie to set cookie. Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: @chandan_kr_jha it's setting the cookie correctly because when i have the `console.log()` for the cookie i see it displayed. I am using the 'react-cookie- package.

Comment: What do you see in logs in express js. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816519/how-to-get-cookie-value-in-expressjs. Are you using cookie-parser in expressjs. If not try the second answer. cookies will be in header.

Comment: I have `app.use(cookieParser());` in my app.js file

Comment: @chandan_kr_jha I am doing what is mentioned in the similar question but it still wont fetch for me. It isn't showing any errors either which is odd

Comment: Can you create a demo in code sandbox. It would be easier to point the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To parse cookies in backend with express, a good choice is to use the https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser middleware.

Provided you are using setup something similar to below

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Every Request object on server will have cookies information in the `req.cookies` property. So in your case it should be `req.cookies.token`