# Send cookie back to client

Tags: node.js, express, http, cookies, passport.js

I'm trying to authenticate my users via google, facebok, and twitter login apis. I open the login page like this:

```
<button @click="signInGoogle" class="btn">Sign in with Google</button>

signInGoogle() {
      window.open(this.baseUrl + "/google", "_self");
    }
```

And then, on my express server, I handle the request. I manage to set the cookie, but how do I get it back on the client?.
My problem is that I'm not listening to the results of an http request, this apis in conjunction with passport are handling it. I can redirect my user like this:

```
 router.get('/success', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:8080')
})
```

But how can I also get the cookie back to the client?
Edit: When I respond with the cookie, I respond to the google sing in pop up, not my client. I need a way to get the results on that new window to my client.

Comment: read about it https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get cookie value in expressjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816519/how-to-get-cookie-value-in-expressjs)

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying so fast! Those articles are helpful to better understand how cookies work,  but it doesn't solve it here. My problem, I think, is that I'm not making a http request from the client, so I don't have a result to listen to. I can res.json(req.cookie) but I have no way to receive it on the client since I'm not listening to it.

Comment: You make a request to `/google` but you listen to `/success`, rename it too to `/google`

Comment: Thanks for helping me Ifaruki. Sadly, I don't think that's the problem. In my client I'm not listening to anything; `/success` is only accessed after the successful authentication, but when I respond, I respond to the google pop up window. What I need is a way to collect the results sent to that new window. Thanks again.